# Add up all values from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray, containing `x` different NSStrings (NSString but only numbers no letters). I would like to add up all of the values to return a single float, or int. I think I have to do this with a for loop, but i am very unfamiliar with for loops....
OK I have reached this point:

```
for (NSString *a in det) 
{
   float x = [a floatValue];
   NSLog(@"%.2f",x);
}
```

And this returns all the values like this in ´NSLog`:

```
23.00
8.00
61.00
...
```

How could i just add them up now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
float total = 0;
for(NSString *str in det)
{
    total += [str floatValue];
}
```

Comment: rats...looks like you beat me to this one =)

Answer (score 14):

You can avoid looping and instead use the `key value coding` and obtain the total

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.1", @"2.2", @"3.1", nil];
    NSNumber *sum = [arr valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.floatValue"];
```

Variable sum will be 6.4.

Comment: I like this. I’m using this technique to see if a user preference has any values selected. I use ---- NSNumber *total1=[prefsCategory1 valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.intValue"]; --- then --- convert it to an int in my conditional ---- if ( [total1 unsignedIntegerValue] > 0 ) {

Comment: Great answer, +1, i was just suffering answer and found good use of KVC.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code for a for-in if you want to save a bit of typing.  It's preferable to use fast enumeration for these types of scenarios with data structures that support it.

```
float result = 0.0;
for(NSString *i in nsArray)
{
    result += [i floatValue];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int result = 0;

for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++) 
     result += [[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

if you need to return a float simply define result as float and use `floatValue` instead of `intValue`